# Когда используется Entity SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Когда к нему прибегают?

Я правильно понимаю, что это средство для создания динамического создания запросов, где целью выступают классы на которые отражаются данные?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду метод [`ExecuteQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) или [`SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx)? Можете уточнить список методов. чтобы вопрос был более конкретен. Также [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) вам интересен или нет?

Comment: Можете ответить на вопрос? Я вам тогда смогу что-то смогу ответить.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov. context.CreateQuery<T>(queryStr)

Answer (score 0):

Это просто устаревшее апи, пользоваться которым нынче не имеет смысла.

В отличие от привычного апи EF позволяет запросить кастомные данные без создания экземпляров каких то конкретных классов, т.е. слабо типизировано.